# Trying to create like a database by pushing arrays

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So basically I've just started programming in JS yesterday (discord.js) and I'm trying to do something like:

```
client.on('message', message => {
        if(message.content.startsWith("%%listeCompteur")) {
            for (i=0; i<pplAddingImages.length-1;i+=2) {
                message.channel.send(pplAddingImages[i] + " : " + pplAddingImages[i+1])
            }
        }
    })
```

creating a "database" if I can call it like that, that extends each time someone is posting an Image in a channel. 
I created a condition before:

```
if(!pplAddingImages.includes('message.author.id')) {
        pplAddingImages.push('message.author.id');
        pplAddingImages.push('0');
    }
```

But it doesn't work at all. When I'm printing the array `pplAddingImages` it shows:

```
message.author.id : 0
```

And even if I'm trying to post an image with an another account, the array doesn't extend with my ID.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Remember to include both *expected* results and *actual* results in your description.

Comment: I'm not really sure whats expected and actual results in my description ?

Comment: You treat your message object as a string. Just remove the quotes around them

Comment: Ohh I see, I'll try this !
Edit : yeah ok, that was dumb... It worked now, thanks =)